# Where to download MXNet pre-trained model file final-0000.params

Tags: mxnet

I followed the tutorial of object detection in mxnet,
http://mxnet.io/tutorials/computer_vision/detection.html
but I don't download the pretrained network and place the extracted file final-0000.params.
Where place I can find the file to download in the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find instructions for downloading the model params for a variety of pre-trained models here: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-model-gallery
and the model files themselves are hosted here: http://data.dmlc.ml/models/

You can pick from a variety of pre-trained models that have varying levels of complexity (computational cost) and accuracy, as well as picking between having 1,000 classes in the standard ImageNet ILSVRC-2012 task, or the full 21,000 class dataset which is more expressive.  Note that the exact filename of the params file varies.

Comment: Thank you,I found the file.I put it in the ./rcnn/ and ran the command python demo.py --prefix final --epoch 0 --image myimage.jpg --gpu 0.There is a error that ValueError: Must specify all the arguments in args.I don't know what error is or how to deal with it.

Comment: If you open a new question with the details of this other error we can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also view various pre-trained MXNet models in MXNet model zoo page. http://mxnet.io/model_zoo/index.html